# Using sequences prove that $f(z)=Re(z)$ and $g(z)=Im(z)$ are continuous.

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, cauchy-riemann-equations

I've found a few proofs showing the continuity with the Cauchy-Riemann equations but am unsure as to whether they are proved using sequences which the question I'm attempting requires. I may be wrong but I think if I just prove that $z_j$ tends towards $z$ if and only if Re(zj) tends towards $Re(z)$ and $Im(z_j)$ tends towards $Im(z)$, then this implies that $Re(z)$ and $Im(z)$ are continuous. If anyone could give the proof that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by continuity of an equation?

Comment: I don't see the relation between your question and Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Your statement '$z_j \rightarrow z$ if and only if $\Re(z_j)\rightarrow  \Re(z)$ and $\Im(z_j) \rightarrow \Im(z)$' is correct. Please use $|z_j -z|^2= |\Re(z_j) -  \Re(z)|^2+|\Im(z_j) - \Im(z)|^2\leqslant (|\Re(z_j) -  \Re(z)|+|\Im(z_j) - \Im(z)|)^2$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor continuity of an equation is whether or not it is continuous.

Comment: @mfl it's related because a lot of the proofs I saw (that don't use sequences) use the CR equations.

Comment: @TeebroProkash thanks for your help

Comment: @NickRilett I only know what it means for a /function/ to be continuous. For example,  what does "$x^2 + y^2 = 0$ is continuous" mean?

Answer (score 1):

We will use the convergence criterion for continuous maps to prove this. 
Let $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of complex numbers converging to $z$. To prove $f$ and $g$ to be continuous, it is enough to prove that $f(z_n) (\text{resp. }  g(z_n))$ converges to $f(z) (\text{resp. } g(z)).$

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given. We know that, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, \begin{align*} 
|z_n - z| &< \epsilon \\
\implies |Re(z_n - z) + i Im(z_n -z)| &< \epsilon \\ \implies |Re(z_n -z)| < \epsilon &\text{ and } |Im(z_n-z)| < \epsilon \\ \implies |Re(z_n) - Re(z)|< \epsilon &\text{ and } |Im(z_n) -Im(z)| < \epsilon \text{ for all } n \geq N. 
\end{align*}
Thus, $Re(z_n) \longrightarrow Re(z)$ and $Im(z_n) \longrightarrow Im(z)$. Hence, the functions $Re(z)$ and $Im(z)$ are continuous.